# Is it true that $\forall n \ge 2, \, \exists p \in \mathbb{P}, v_p(n(n+1)(n+2))=1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Is it true that $\forall n \ge 2, \, \exists p \in \mathbb{P}, v_p(n(n+1)(n+2))=1$?

For small values of $n$, we see that
$$
2\times 3 \times 4 \to 3\\
3\times 4 \times 5 \to 3\\
4\times 5 \times 6 \to 5\\
5\times 6 \times 7 \to 5\\
6\times 7 \times 8 \to 7\\
7\times 8 \times 9 \to 7\\
8\times 9 \times 10 \to 5\\
9\times 10 \times 11 \to 11\\
10\times 11 \times 12 \to 11\\
11\times 12 \times 13 \to 11\\
12\times 13 \times 14 \to 13\\
\vdots
$$
I'd conjecture that it's true but I don't see how to begin my proof.

Comment: @player3236 Almost, but $p=3$ works.  The question is whether $n(n+1)(n+2)$ is ever a so-called powerful number; equivalently, a number of the form $a^2 b^3$.  Since no two of $n$, $n+1$, and $n+2$ can share a factor other than 2, this can only happen if either all three are powerful themselves, or the first two or last two are powerful and the other is 2 times a powerful odd number.  Apparently it's an open conjecture of Erdős that the first case can't happen.

Comment: OEIS has a list of pairs of consecutive powerful numbers:  https://oeis.org/A060355.  None of the ones listed (up to 28821995554247) can be extended to a counterexample to this conjecture.

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A076445 for pairs $n$ and $n+2$ of consecutive odd powerful numbers.

Comment: Says the comment at the OEIS sequence @Sil linked: "Erdős conjectured that there aren't three consecutive powerful numbers and no examples are known." So you've been beaten to the conjecture by Erdős. Not a bad mathematician to be beaten by ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer OP's conjecture is a little stronger than Erdős's, in that it predicts that triples of the form (even powerful, odd powerful, $2 \cdot$ odd powerful) (or the reverse) also can't happen.  In any case, it's probably true, but almost certainly very hard to prove.

Comment: @RaviFernando Right, I missed that, thanks. And I agree with "probably true, but ...".